# Controlling number of related row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Let an scenario where a system have brands and each brand has many branches.

### Brand

- id : int
- name : string
- max_num_branch : int

---

### Branch

- id : int
- name : string
- brand_id : foreign to Brand table

In this schema, the system needs to maintain that maximum number of `branch`es for each `brand` is `brand.max_num_branch`.

This can be done by counting just before adding/updating branch under any brand. But is there any direct way to add this constrain except writing procedures.

Mysql is being used with laravel here.

Comment: MySQL does not yet support check constraints.  Without this, I'm not sure this can be implemented at the database level.  Perhaps there may be a way to enforce this via Laravel +1.

Comment: If laravel uses InnoDB (or you migrate the table(s) to InnoDB) this can be done easily and safely through transactions.

Comment: @RingØ can you explain a little bit more. It seems interesting to me.

Comment: Mainly InnoDB ensures DB consistency thanks to transactions (among other things). Meaning if you check the count, and then insert, what happens if somebody else (another session) modifies count *between* the two operations? InnoDB will lock count in the transaction until you're done (ie after inserting the branch)

Comment: @RingØ if you have time give an answer attaching proper example. I may accept if work. And yes, I am using InnoDB.